# Writing effectively under very brief constraints

Tags: style, technique, word-choice, process, prose

I recently noticed a trend to a few of my questions. I am attracted to writing in places with extreme brevity. This makes sense to me on a personal level. I've always been attracted to one-liners and short but powerful works. I like reading and writing works that deliver a lot of value quickly and I agonize over word choice to leverage meaning whenever possible.

What I want to know is, are there any techniques, or strategies, to deliver more impact in short works? What I do right now is by feel. Then I often revise, revise, revise. I can often make twenty passes through a piece of work with the intention of distilling it. Making it shorter in breadth but still containing as much or more meaning. **Is there any formula, pattern, etc... that can help me in this process?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Research **soundbites**.

Someone who claims to write "the art of the soundbite" has invented a system he calls A BEACH PRO:

> The system is called A BEACH PRO, which is an acronym that stands for **analogy**, **bold action words**, **emotions**, **examples**, **attacks**, **absolutes**, **clichés**, **humor**, **pop culture references**, **rhetorical questions** and **opposition quotes**.
>
> Nearly every quote you read in newspapers and trade publications
>   contains one or more of these 11 A BEACH PRO elements.

The advice seems pretty broad and the acronym would actually be A BEEAACH PRO, but it does seem to get to the "impact" you mention – not accuracy or brevity, but "impact".

Neil deGrasse Tyson has a [talk about soundbites](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fic_a1VfzEI) where he describes 3 sentences that are: "informative, make you smile, and are so tasty you might want to tell someone else."